# executable pointing to rbenv instead of homebrew

Tags: rbenv

Installed `gem 'image_optim_bin'`, but it didn't work.

```
$ jpegoptim
/Users/aj/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/image_optim_bin-0.0.4/bin/jpegoptim:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ELF (NameError)
    from /Users/aj/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/jpegoptim:23:in `load'
    from /Users/aj/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/jpegoptim:23:in `<main>'
```

So uninstalled, and installed with homebrew.

```
$ gem uninstall image_optim_bin
Remove executables? [Yn]  Y

$ brew install jpegoptim

$ brew unlink jpegoptim && brew link jpegoptim
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/jpegoptim/1.4.0... 2 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpegoptim/1.4.0... 2 symlinks created

$ which jpegoptim
/Users/aj/.rbenv/shims/jpegoptim

$ gem list | egrep 'jpe?g|optim'
```

Why is it still pointing to the rbenv path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here for myself in 2 months. Gotta rehash!

```
$ rbenv rehash
$ jpegoptim
jpegoptim: file arguments missing
Try 'jpegoptim --help' for more information.
```